# Invalid endpoint: https://s3.us_east_1.amazonaws.com while invoking the aws lambda list?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have configured with all the correct details,**strong text**could someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly configured your Lambda function to use an endpoint of `s3.us_east_1` when [it should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) `s3.us-east-1`. You must have configured it that way yourself somehow, because the AWS SDK would not just convert dashes to underscores by itself.